# Saving to DB from Model.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When an new order_preview is created, I call USPS for shipping options.  If a user updates their zip, I would like the ship_option to reset

Edit: I am no longer calling the intial API call from the view, rather I do an after_create method in the controller.

```
def get_ship_options
ship_options = {}
      @order_preview.fedex_rates.each do |k, v|
          if k.service_name == "FedEx Ground Home Delivery" || k.service_name == "FedEx 2 Day" || k.service_name == "FedEx Standard Overnight"
      ship_options["#{k.service_name}"] = "#{number_to_currency(k.price.to_f / 100)}"
    end
      end
      @order_preview.usps_rates.each do |k, v|
          if k.service_name == "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day"
      ship_options["#{k.service_name}"] = "#{number_to_currency(k.price.to_f / 100)}"
          end
      end
  @order_preview.ship_option_hash = ship_options.map { |k,v| ["#{k} - #{v}","#{k} - #{v}" ] }
  @order_preview.save
end
```

I tried using the answers you guys provided, but the before_save didn't actually save the shiphash the way @order_preview.save does at the end of the above method.

I tried using the same idea, but `zip_changed?` doesn't work in the controller.

How can I save the new hash  that is pulled from the model directly over to the @order_preview ?

From the model I now have

Model.rb

```
def clear_hash
 if zip_changed? 
  get_shipping_rates
 end
end
```

and

```
       ship_options = {}
        fedex_rates.each do |k, v|
            if k.service_name == "FedEx Ground Home Delivery" || k.service_name == "FedEx 2 Day" || k.service_name == "FedEx Standard Overnight"
                ship_options["#{k.service_name}"] = "#{number_to_currency(k.price.to_f / 100)}"
            end
        end
        usps_rates.each do |k, v|
            if k.service_name == "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day"
                ship_options["#{k.service_name}"] = "#{number_to_currency(k.price.to_f / 100)}"
            end
        end
        ship_option_hash = ship_options.map { |k,v| ["#{k} - #{v}","#{k} - #{v}" ] }
**save ship_option_hash to @order_preview.ship_option_hash**
```

Comment: Models in ruby are what many languages would refer to as classes; they are primarily used to describe what an object should be.  While the views are for giving a model substance and the controller is sort of the glue that ties the whole process together.  The process of submitting data is managed by the controller but not without a bit of help from the page lifecycle and some extra views.  (This is my understanding of the separation of responsibilities within the rails code, which it seemed you were asking about to me...)

Answer (score 1):

```
class OrderPreview
  before_save :check_state

  def check_state
    if zip_changed?
      ship_option_hash = nil
    end
  end
  ...
end

class OrderPreviewController
  def update
    @order_preview.update(order_preview_params)
  end
...
end
```

Comment: That should be self.option_hash_changed = nil

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your callback from after_save to before_save. Record considered changed until the changes are not persisted. Changes are lost when you save your object, that's why your record is unchanged when you check for changes in after_save callback.

It should work this way:

```
before_save :clear_hash, if: :zip_changed?

def clear_hash
   ship_option_hash = nil
end
```

This way the changes will be saved, because you use before_save. In your code, changes were not saved, because you used after_save callback

You controller:

```
def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @order_preview.update(order_preview_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Record was successfully updated"
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Record  was not updated"
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: updated my question, this idea is good but it didn't actually save the new hash when I did a raise at the next show page